# Is there a Drupal module that can create a content type from an SQL Query or a CSV file?

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a Drupal module that can create a content type from an SQL Query or a CSV file?

I am looking for a module which can carry out the process itself, at least based on simple types like strings, dates, floats, and integers, something that can use an SQL table definition to create it.

Another option is one that provides a form similar to the table creation dialogs in database applications like SQLite Manager or Microsoft Access, where you specify the name of the field, the size and the type and  the system goes off to carry out the task.

Answer (score 1):

A module referred to as [ECK](https://drupal.org/project/eck) has the functionality you're looking for.

Although, it works in the entity system to create new entity types. You might be looking for something to pragmatically create entity bundles (node content types). I would suggest researching the [difference between Entity's and Bundles](http://dikini.net/31.08.2010/entities_bundles_fields_and_field_instances) if you're not familiar.